# What is the name for Boolean algebra's version of $\models$ between sets of identities and identities?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, computer-science, universal-algebra, boolean-algebras

On p62 in Schaum's Outline of Theory and Problems of Boolean Algebra and Switching Circuits by Elliott Mendelson (1970),

[image]

Part (b) of the corollary  says that if an identity is satisfied by some algebra which  satisfies the axioms of Boolean algebras, then it is satisfied by any algebra  which  satisfies the axioms of Boolean algebras.

In model theory, logic, and universal algebra, consider the following statement

> Given a set of formulas or identities, if a formula or identity is satisfied by some (algebraic) structure which satisfies the set of formulas or identities, then it is also satisfied by any (algebraic)
> structure  which satisfies the set of formulas or identities.

- Is it true that the statement isn't true in general?
- Is the statement true in a context other than or  more general than Boolean algebra?
- Is there a name for the concept or property represented by the statement, either in Boolean algebra, or more generally in universal algebra, logic, or model theory?
- Is the concept or property represented by the statement mentioned in some standard books in Boolean algebra, logic (e.g. Ebbinghaus'), universal algebra (e.g. Burris'), or model theory (e.g. Chang's)? (Burris' universal algebra  book has  Chapter IV on Boolean algebra, which I wonder if has relevant coverage, and the chapter is not as easy to access as Mendelson's  book  for me now.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the name for this idea is **equationally complete theory**, see page 30 of [Walter Taylor's Equational Logic survey](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Ehjm/hjmathsurvey_1979.pdf).

Not every theory is like that:
for example in the theory of lattices, which is defined by axioms such as
$$x\wedge (y\wedge z)=(x\wedge y)\wedge z$$
(the full list is at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#General_lattice))
some are distributive and some are not.
So
$$x\wedge (y\vee z)=(x\wedge y)\vee x(\wedge z)$$
is an identity that holds in some but not all lattices.

Comment: Thanks. Is your example a counter-example to part (b) of the corollary?

Comment: @Tim yes but anyway (a) and (b) seem to be equivalent by the Completeness Theorem.

Comment: Your example is a counter-example to the Completeness Theorem?

Comment: No, because the distributive law is not provable from the axioms defining lattices